# What is the behavior of dplyr::filter when a vector is used as an argument for equality?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, data-science, tibble

I know we can use `dplyr::filter` to filter for multiple values in a column using logical OR:

```
library(tidyverse)
diamonds
# A tibble: 53,940 x 10

filter(diamonds, cut == 'Good' | cut == 'Premium')
# A tibble: 18,697 x 10
```

And we can use the `%in%` operator together with a vector to simplify this syntax:

```
filter(diamonds, cut %in% c('Good', 'Premium'))
# A tibble: 18,697 x 10
```

All good. But what happens if I use:

```
filter(diamonds, cut == c('Good', 'Premium'))
# A tibble: 9,369 x 10
```

The resulting tibble contains only `'Good'` and `'Premium'` values on the `diamonds$cut` column, as reported by `unique`. However, it contains roughly half the total rows of the previous, properly-filtered examples.

At first I thought R was skipping every other row, but after running `head` on the results, that doesn't seem to be the case. Can anyone shed some light on what's going on internally with the last example?

Comment: Vector *recycling* is the key here.

Comment: In first approach your process compares each `cut` value with `'Good'` and `''Premium`. In the second one it splits `cut` column in vectors of 2 (e.g. values 1-2, 3-4, etc.) and compares the first value of each pair with `'Good'` only and the second value with `'Premium'` only. You can better understand the second approach via this example `diamonds$col = c('Good', 'Premium');
diamonds %>% filter(cut == col)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the point here is that the vector you are passing gets recycled: `'Good', 'Premium', 'Good', 'Premium'...`. You can see this if you create this as a variable:

```
df %>%
    mutate(filterThis = cut == c('Good', 'Premium'))

   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z filterThis
   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>     
 1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43 FALSE     
 2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31 TRUE      
 3 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31 TRUE      
 4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63 TRUE      
 5 0.31  Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75 TRUE      
 6 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48 FALSE     
 7 0.24  Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47 FALSE     
 8 0.26  Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53 FALSE     
 9 0.22  Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49 FALSE     
10 0.23  Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39 FALSE
```

Imagine the `'Good', 'Premium', 'Good', 'Premium'...` and compare it with the `cut`column.

Comment: try also `filter(tail(diamonds,-1), cut == c('Good', 'Premium'))`. Then the error will indicate the recycling

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I'm still getting used to R's syntax. Honestly this behavior is something I'd expect from a `cycle` function, but it probably has its use cases.

Comment: of course. try this easy one `data.frame(a=1:10, b=3, d=1:2)[c(T, F),]`